# Timely Gradle task inputs/outputs configuration

Tags: gradle

I'm having ordering issues with Gradle task configuration.

I'm writing a plugin that creates a task based on information that is only available when supplied via the build script. I can create the task in the plugin's `apply()` method, and configure it in its `doFirst()` method (by which time the necessary information is available). However, I also want to make sure that the task is only executed when necessary via the `inputs`/`outputs` properties.

This is problematic, because I have to do this in the `apply()` method (as far as I can tell), but at that point the information required to specify the `inputs`/`outputs` property values isn't available.

I tried using a convention object but that's not available under after `apply()` has completed.

Is there any way around this that won't make me feel dirty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those parts of the task configuration that need to be deferred, you can either use a hook like `project.afterEvaluate {}` or `gradle.projectsEvaluated {}`, or use convention *mapping*. The latter is used extensively by Gradle's own plugins, but isn't currently considered a public API.